# Create Excel file if it doesn't exist before export SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to export some SQL Server tables to Excel but the Excel file must already exist otherwise the SSIS would throw an error. Any way to tell SSIS to create the excel file with the correct columns if the Excel file doesn't exist?

When I try to click on mapping without the proper Excel file already made it throws error below:

[image]

Comment: You could add a Script Block that uses the EPPlus library from NuGet to create the Excel file with the desired worksheets and column headers. But if you're going to that amount of trouble you might as well have that Script Block handle the whole export for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Create three variables in your SSIS Package
  `FolderPath`  : provide the folder path in which you want to check the file
  `FileName` : provide the file name
  `FileExistsFlg` : we will use this to indicate file exists or not. 1 means exists and 0 means does not exists.

After creating variables, Drag Script Task to the Control Flow Pane and Provide Variables and Finally Click on Edit Script :

[image]

In the `Task Script` :

```
public void Main()
{

String Filepath=Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].ValueToString()+Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
if( File.Exists(FilePath))
{ Dts.Variables["User::FileExissFlg"].Value=1; }

Dts.TaskResult= (int) ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Use the variable `FileExistsFlg` to run the next tasks if file exists (FileExistsFlg=1).

Bring Data Flow task in Control Flow Pane and Connect Script Task to it.

Double click on Green line ( Precedence Constraint) between two tasks.

Choose Expression and Constraint from Evaluation operation drop down and in Value choose "Success". In expression write `@FileExistsFlg==1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I ended up going with.  Grab a new "Execute SQL Task".

```
ConnectionType = EXCEL, 
Connection = [YOU'R EXCEL CONNECTION MANAGER], 
SQLStatement = CREATE TABLE YourTable(COL1 VARCHAR(10))
```

Finally set the Excel Destination DelayValidation = True and put the Execute SQL Task in front of the Excel destination somewhere in Control Flow.

This will probably throw an error if the file already exist but for my use case it's good enough.